# Fiddler can't track commands of chrome devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, fiddler

I work in windows with the program that starts and controls the chrome-based browser.

Fiddler can display all the traffic from that browser, but I want to explore the commands that are sent to that browser to control it (for example open URL, make a post query, etc).

Fiddler doesn't display such commands.

But using ieinspector HttpAnalyzer I can see that the browser is controlled by the chrome devtools at localhost:54909 and websockets ws://localhost/devtools/page/HASH

[image]

How can I explore all that information in fiddler?

Comment: Of course Fiddler can only see network traffic. For monitoring program executions try Sysinternals Process Monitor and disable file, registry and network tracing.

Comment: Fiddler can monitor WebSockets traffic. As you can see on the screenshot, HttpAnalyzer explicitly displays that WebSocket connection, but fiddler for some reason can't display it. And I don't get why.